# Generate a key with keytool, in a non-interactive way

Tags: android, windows, keystore, keytool

When I'm using:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\keytool.exe" -genkey 
     -v -keystore my.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias app
```

then an interactive process begins which asks name, password, etc.

**Is there a way to have a non-interactive generation of keys, where parameters are directly in the command line parameters?**

Comment: Which difficulties do you have with password

Comment: @user8773560 it's not about just password, but the fact that the interactive process asks 10 questions: name, password, organization, etc. I'd prefer to pass all these things in a command line script.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This works:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore my.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 \
        -validity 10000 -alias app -dname "cn=Unknown, ou=Unknown, o=Unknown, c=Unknown" \
        -storepass abcdef12 -keypass abcdef12
```

Comment: Right @Basj, works as documented under [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).